# Fancybox to open pdf won't work on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, pdf, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

Im using fancybox to show pdf.

And its working fine, when I click in my links with class="fancybox_pdf", the pdf opens like I wanted!

The problem is in mobile, Im testing this also in my smartphone, and When I click to open my link with class="fancybox_pdf", the pdf is transferred and  the fancybox opens empty, .

Do you know if this is normal? Fancybox to open pdf dont work on mobile devices?

(If i resize my browser for the mobile version on desktop, the fancybox with pdf also works fine)

This is my html:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>    
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="fancybox_pdf" href="../pdf/pdf1.pdf">PDF 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="fancybox_pdf" href="../pdf/pdf2.pdf">PDF 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="fancybox_pdf" href="../pdf/pdf3.pdf">PDF 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

I have this jQuery script:

```
 $(".fancybox_pdf").fancybox({
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        autoSize: false,
        type: 'iframe',
        iframe: {
            preload: false
        } 
});
```

Comment: does this work for you on mobile http://jsfiddle.net/wdnEM/2/show/ ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer JFK. And with that jsfiddle that you gave me,  happens the same thing that Im having with my example. I start to download the pdf, and fancybox opens blank!

Comment: do you have installed adobe reader in your phone?

Comment: I didnt have, but I download it now, and the problem continues :/

Comment: what mobile device? can you share a link?

Comment: Samsung galaxy express! Sorry, but I didnt understand whay you said saying to share a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there seem to be multiple problems with "PDF viewer" - applications in mobile browsers. though `iframe` is supported by most of them, it seems like most of them can't embed a "PDF viewer" into itself.

but here i found a very promising alternative solution, based on html5 and javascript only: [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)

you'll need some access rights on your webserver and `github` to install it, tho.